# How do I access the same IoC container (i.e. Unity) in multiple classes?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, prism, ioc-container

How do I access the same IoC container (i.e. Unity) in multiple classes?

The following container is a local variable when embedded inside a method.
As a result, How do I access this container in other classes?

```
    using (var container = new UnityContainer())
    {
        container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IDraftRepository), new MockDraftRepository());
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need the container in your classes?

Comment: Can you elaborate more why you need to do this?

Comment: I need to access resources across my view-models. As a result, I was under the assumption that I need the same container reference within my various view-models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a static class and make it expose the container as a property. Then all the other classes can access and use it. Another way is to inject `IUnityContainer` into the classes that want to use it (via constructor injection).

Having said that, I strongly recommend that you don't do this. The only place where the container should be used is the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) which is where you compose all of your classes together in the entry point of the application.

And if your classes need dependencies, you can inject them in the constructor.

Using the container in your classes is called Service Location [and is considered an anti-pattern](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/10/object-composability-another-reason-why.html).

Comment: My "current" job is forcing me to use an IoC container. Thanks. I assume in my classes, I use the ServiceLocator static class instead of the actual container. Is that what your referring to?

Comment: I didn't say in my answer that you shouldn't use an IoC container, I said that you should use it in a specific place in your application. My first suggestion was to use the service locator via a static class, yes. Because in any case, your are using the service locator anti-pattern.

Comment: This may not fully address the question. It looks to me like the OP is creating an instance of a `UnityContainer` within some method and wants that same container instance available elsewhere in the object graph. It looks more like a child container\lifetime issue to me. The service locator may need to be context aware ....

Comment: I guess that OP should add more context to the question then.